# Rails 4 missing local variables for partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

Per [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) if you render partial using a collection: , the partial will have rendered record accessible with name of the partial. However my partials are throwing error:

Here is the Template: `= render "todo", collection: @ntodos, as: 'todo' || "none"`

here is _todo.html.haml partial:

```
%div 
    %h3= todo.title
    %div
```

Answer (score 2):

tldr; you need to `render partial: 'todo', collection: ...`.

---

That isn't how you render a collection partial, that's how you render a partial and pass locals to it.

Rendering partial has two different an incompatible syntaxes.

The first way is `render(options_hash)`. It looks like this:

```
render partial: 'template', locals: { var1: value1 }
```

The second way (which you've used) cannot render collections. It uses a `render(template_name, locals_hash)` signature, something like this:

```
render 'template', var1: value1
```

Your invocation, which uses the second form, rendered `todo` and passed two locals named `collection` and `as` to it.

If you want to render a collection, you need to explicitly use the first form, with `render partial: 'todo', collection: @ntodos, as: 'todo'`